# Silverlight default selection in combobox

Tags: silverlight

I populate a combobox with some data from ria services. This is basically used for filtering by countries. But I also want to have a filter by "all". How would I do this when ria service over writes the data i set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by on receiving the data, inserting a line at 0 for "ALL" and then when changing selection, if all is selected do 1 thing, else restrict by country etc.